# Importing Edge List into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, csv, import, line

I have a CSV edge list such as follows:

```
Lat1,Lon1,Lat2,Lon2
93.41823,-104.324324,93.41828,-104.324320
93.40110,-104.310552,93.40108,-104.310557
...
```

Is there a way to import such a CSV file into QGis such that the edges show up as lines?

Answer (score 1):

Replace test.csv with the correct filename and paste the following code into the Python console. Note, that in your csv Lat=y comes before Lon=x.

```
# specify your csv-file
csvFile = "G:/test.csv"

# create an empty memory layer for polylines
layer = QgsVectorLayer('LineString?crs=EPSG:4326', 'Connected', 'memory')
prov = layer.dataProvider()

# add layer to the map
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

# open the csv-file for reading and skip the header row
lineStrings = open(csvFile, "rU")
next(lineStrings)

# start editing
layer.startEditing()

# loop over the lines, split them into 4 coordinates, build points from pairs of
# them, and connect the pair of points 
feats = []
for line in lineStrings:
    lineStringAsList = line.split(",")
    from_node = QgsPoint(float(lineStringAsList[1]),float(lineStringAsList[0]))
    to_node = QgsPoint(float(lineStringAsList[3]),float(lineStringAsList[2]))
    feat = QgsFeature()
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([from_node, to_node]))
    feats.append(feat)

# finally add all created features and save edits
prov.addFeatures(feats)
layer.updateExtents()
layer.commitChanges()
```

Please check your latitude values, they are out of range [-90, 90].