# Error when "Importing edge list into QGIS"

Tags: qgis, csv

**Problem**

I have tried to import edges to QGIS as indicated here:

[Importing Edge List into QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151458/importing-edge-list-into-qgis/435357?noredirect=1#comment710308_435357)

However, I got an error when I try to perform this command

```py
prov.addFeatures(feats)
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/code.py", line 63, in runsource
    code = self.compile(source, filename, symbol)
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/codeop.py", line 178, in __call__
    return _maybe_compile(self.compiler, source, filename, symbol)
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/codeop.py", line 106, in _maybe_compile
    raise err1
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/codeop.py", line 93, in _maybe_compile
    code1 = compiler(source + "\n", filename, symbol)
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/codeop.py", line 143, in __call__
    codeob = compile(source, filename, symbol, self.flags, 1)
  File "<input>", line 8
    prov.addFeatures(feats)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to solve it ?

**_______________________________________________________________**

**Here below the original code from** [Importing Edge List into QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151458/importing-edge-list-into-qgis/435357?noredirect=1#comment710308_435357)

Replace test.csv with the correct filename and paste the following code into the Python console. Note, that in your csv Lat=y comes before Lon=x.

```py
# specify your csv-file
csvFile = "G:/test.csv"

# create an empty memory layer for polylines
layer = QgsVectorLayer('LineString?crs=EPSG:4326', 'Connected', 'memory')
prov = layer.dataProvider()

# add layer to the map
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

# open the csv-file for reading and skip the header row
lineStrings = open(csvFile, "rU")
next(lineStrings)

# start editing
layer.startEditing()

# loop over the lines, split them into 4 coordinates, build points from pairs of
# them, and connect the pair of points 
feats = []
for line in lineStrings:
    lineStringAsList = line.split(",")
    from_node = QgsPoint(float(lineStringAsList[1]),float(lineStringAsList[0]))
    to_node = QgsPoint(float(lineStringAsList[3]),float(lineStringAsList[2]))
    feat = QgsFeature()
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([from_node, to_node]))
    feats.append(feat)

# finally add all created features and save edits
prov.addFeatures(feats)
layer.updateExtents()
layer.commitChanges()
```

Please check your latitude values, they are out of range [-90, 90].
**_______________________________________________________________**

Comment: Please include relevant code in your question, since links are subject to change.

Comment: It looks like this script is for QGIS2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python script that you provide is for QGIS 2, so this will be the code for QGIS 3.

```py
# specify your csv-file
csvFile = "G:/test.csv"

# create an empty memory layer for polylines
layer = QgsVectorLayer('LineString?crs=EPSG:4326', 'Connected', 'memory')
# prov = layer.dataProvider() now is not necessary to use a QgsDataProvider object to handle layers

# add layer to the map
# QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer) # this is the way to add layer to the QGIS project

# open the csv-file for reading and skip the header row
lineStrings = open(csvFile, "rU")
next(lineStrings)

# start editing
layer.startEditing()

# loop over the lines, split them into 4 coordinates, build points from pairs of
# them, and connect the pair of points 
feats = []
for line in lineStrings:
    lineStringAsList = line.split(",")
    from_node = QgsPoint(float(lineStringAsList[1]),float(lineStringAsList[0]))
    to_node = QgsPoint(float(lineStringAsList[3]),float(lineStringAsList[2]))
    feat = QgsFeature()
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([from_node, to_node]))
    feats.append(feat)

# finally add all created features and save edits
# prov.addFeatures(feats)
layer.addFeatures(feats) # add features to the layer object, now you don't need to add layers to a QgsDataProvider object
layer.updateExtents()
layer.commitChanges()
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Mayo! The code runs well but I do not see anything in the main window of QGIS....

Comment: It worked fine for me, but remember that the first column must be the y coordinate of the first point and the second column is the x coordinate of the first point, then the third column must be the y coordinate of the second point and the fourth column is the x coordinate of the second point

Comment: it works!!!! :-) many many thanks!!!

Comment: Please don't just dump a lot of code without a comment. What did you change and why?

Comment: Sorry, I commented every line that is from QGIS 2 and I put below QGIS 3 code, I will edit my question to add more details.